# Wifi Networks Always in Range

Tags: wi-fi

I'm using a samsung galaxy s4 on T-Mobile and I have been experiencing a problem where two wifi networks always appear in range. These networks are not my own, and do not appear to be my hotspot name. They appear even when I travel from one city to another. They always appear with the same name. I am beginning to think it is something malicious because the networks disappear after I perform a factory reset of my phone, and reappear within a few days.
I am pretty selective of which apps I allow to run on my phone. With very few exceptions most of my apps are from trusted developers like google, microsoft, facebook, dropbox etc.
Has anyone experienced a situation like mine?

Comment: Well, that's weird anyway, is it possible for you to share a screen shot when it all started appearing ??

Answer (score 0):

This might be an ad-hoc network that you have accidently connected to. Ad-hoc netowrks is like a network where every device is a router (Very brief there). You can check this just by clicking on the network. You can also just click "forget" on the network after clicking on it in wifi menu.